# AWS SNS not working with APNS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

Having hard time to troubleshoot what's going wrong with my implementation of push notifications service using Amazon SNS. I created the provisioning profiles for debug and release environments and generated the certificate.

Then, I created two platform endpoints on SNS: one for sandbox mode and another for production. However, after registering the device (platform endpoint) in the correct environment, I cannot receive push notification as it goes disabled and CloudWatch says the following as the result of delivery:

`"providerResponse": "{\"reason\":\"DeviceTokenNotForTopic\"}",
"statusCode": 400`

I tested the delivery of push notifications directly with Apple's endpoint with the same certificate and device token:

`curl -v -d '{"aps":{"alert":"MESSAGE"}}' -H "apns-topic: BUNDLE_ID" -H "apns-priority: 10" --http2 --cert CERTIFICATE.pem https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/APNS_DEVICE_TOKEN`

Everything worked as expected, I received the push notification right away on my device. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes, decided to use `fastlane pem` to generate certificates and it worked straightforward. So, I believe it was something with *openssl* converting certificate to the format accepted by SNS (*.pem to *.p12).

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error message. Looking at https://docs.telerik.com/platform/knowledge-base/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ios-push-notification-error-devicetokennotfortopic it turned out that I'd generated my certificate for my production app id, but my app where I was getting the device token was my dev app (with a different app id). I regenerated the certificate and private key -- this time for my dev app id, re-uploaded that to AWS SNS (with a new "Platform Application") and it's now working.